# Fetching json object from JSON string

Tags: android, json, listview, parsing, gson

I am new to Android and I am developing app which has server side functionality. I am getting response in JSON format.

My response is shown as this image.

I know how to parse json using Volley but I don't know hot to parse using GSON. Previous code of my app was written by some one else. Now I have to complete this code. but I do not know how he getting data from JSON string.

I need JSON arrays in different activity. Array response:

[image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9qgugNyvGRiWmRDNDFBOEt1WFU)

Here is some snaps of my code.

Code for adapter for activity one

```
  topicListAdapter = new TopicListAdapter(TopicActivity.this,

                myCourseListMain.  getCourseArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(course_position)).
                getTopicListMain().getTopicDetailsArrayList(), flag);


        listAlltopics.setAdapter(topicListAdapter);
```

in which I got list of topics

here is code for second activity list adapter

```
 lessionListAdapter = new LessionListAdapter(LessionActivity.this,
                myCourseListMain.  getCourseArrayList().      get(Integer.parseInt(course_position)).
                getTopicListMain().getTopicDetailsArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(topic_position)).getLessionArrayList(), flag);
```

by this code i got array of lession in second activity

Now I want sublession array in third activity but I don't know how to get it.
Here is what I tried

```
 lessionListAdapter = new DummyAdapter(DummyTopicList.this,
                myCourseListMain     .  getCourseArrayList().         get(Integer.parseInt(course_position)).
                getTopicListMain()   .  getTopicDetailsArrayList()   .get(Integer.parseInt(topic_position)).
                getLessionLIstMain() .getLessionLIstDetailArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(lession_position)). , flag);

        listAlllessions.setAdapter(lessionListAdapter);
```

Here are some other classes which helpful to you for understand

```
public class MyCourseListMain {

@SerializedName("data")
private ArrayList<Course> courseArrayList;

public ArrayList<Course> getCourseArrayList() {
    return courseArrayList;
}

public void setCourseArrayList(ArrayList<Course> courseArrayList) {
    this.courseArrayList = courseArrayList;    
}
}
```

class for course

```
public class Course {


@SerializedName("img")
private String img;

@SerializedName("title")
private String title;

@SerializedName("institute_id")
private String institute_id;

@SerializedName("institute_name")
private String institute_name;

@SerializedName("expired")
private String expired;

@SerializedName("status")
private String status;

@SerializedName("subscribe_box")
private String subscribe_box;

@SerializedName("expire_on")
private String expire_on;

@SerializedName("item_id")
private String item_id;

@SerializedName("rated")
private String rated;

private TopicListMain topicListMain;



public String getRated() {
    return rated;
}

public void setRated(String rated) {
    this.rated = rated;
}

public String getImg() {
    return img;
}

public void setImg(String img) {
    this.img = img;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getInstitute_id() {
    return institute_id;
}

public void setInstitute_id(String institute_id) {
    this.institute_id = institute_id;
}

public String getInstitute_name() {
    return institute_name;
}

public void setInstitute_name(String institute_name) {
    this.institute_name = institute_name;
}

public String getExpired() {
    return expired;
}

public void setExpired(String expired) {
    this.expired = expired;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getSubscribe_box() {
    return subscribe_box;
}

public void setSubscribe_box(String subscribe_box) {
    this.subscribe_box = subscribe_box;
}

public String getExpire_on() {
    return expire_on;
}

public void setExpire_on(String expire_on) {
    this.expire_on = expire_on;
}

public String getItem_id() {
    return item_id;
}

public void setItem_id(String item_id) {
    this.item_id = item_id;
}

public TopicListMain getTopicListMain() {
    return topicListMain;
}

public void setTopicListMain(TopicListMain topicListMain) {
    this.topicListMain = topicListMain;   }  }
```

class for topiclist_main

```
public class TopicListMain {


@SerializedName("data")
private ArrayList<TopicDetails> topicDetailsArrayList;

public ArrayList<TopicDetails> getTopicDetailsArrayList() {
    return topicDetailsArrayList;
}



public void setTopicDetailsArrayList(ArrayList<TopicDetails> topicDetailsArrayList) {

    this.topicDetailsArrayList = topicDetailsArrayList;   }}
```

class for topic details

```
public class TopicDetails 
{


@SerializedName("topic_id")
private String topic_id;

@SerializedName("title")
private String title;

@SerializedName("locked")
private String locked;

@SerializedName("lessons")
private ArrayList<Lession> lessionArrayList;


private LessionLIstMain lessionLIstMain;

public LessionLIstMain getLessionLIstMain() {
    return lessionLIstMain;
}

public void setLessionLIstMain(LessionLIstMain lessionLIstMain) {
    this.lessionLIstMain = lessionLIstMain;
}

public String getTopic_id() {
    return topic_id;
}

public void setTopic_id(String topic_id) {
    this.topic_id = topic_id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLocked() {
    return locked;
}

public void setLocked(String locked) {
    this.locked = locked;
}

public ArrayList<Lession> getLessionArrayList() {
    return lessionArrayList;
}



public void setLessionArrayList(ArrayList<Lession> lessionArrayList) {
    this.lessionArrayList = lessionArrayList;   }}
```

Comment: What do you exactly want? Do you want to parse the json in the image through Gson?

Comment: This question contained a lot of begging, txtspk and typos, and was not indicative of the kind of good effort we want to see in questions. If you are posting on a mobile phone, are you able to use a laptop or a PC when you post here?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: no brother image is just for reference my json response in look like in image. i want to get  sublesson array in my activity's listview. problem is previous code of this project writen by someone lese.and i am not aware of Gson i am able to do json parsing with volly but in gson i dnt have any idea. @vinit saxena

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/google/gson
Make your object have same construct with your data which you got.And

```
YourObject val = new Gson().fromJson(new String(YourString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),
"UTF-8"), YourObject.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

finally i got my solution by below code.

```
   lessionListAdapter = new DummyAdapter(DummyTopicList.this,
                myCourseListMain     .  getCourseArrayList().         get(Integer.parseInt(course_position)).
                getTopicListMain()   .  getTopicDetailsArrayList()   .get(Integer.parseInt(topic_position)).
                getLessionArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt((lession_position))).getLessionLIstDetailArrayList() , flag);
              listAlllessions.setAdapter(lessionListAdapter);
```

i also made some few classes to handle json array.

```
public class SubLessionDetail {
@SerializedName("lesson_id")
private String lession_id;

@SerializedName("title")
private String title;

@SerializedName("locked")
private String locked;


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLocked() {
    return locked;
}

public void setLocked(String locked) {
    this.locked = locked;
}

public String getLession_id() {

    return lession_id;
}

public void setLession_id(String lession_id) {
    this.lession_id = lession_id;
}
}
```